# How to identify user associated with a certain object in Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a `Product` class in `Parse`, and I'm trying to identify the user and their email associated with a product when selected. In my `Product` class, I do have a user pointer.

Here is what I have so far:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        let product: PFObject = PFObject(className: "Product")

        let createdBy: AnyObject! = product.objectForKey("user")?.email



        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row), created by \(createdBy)!")
```

The code just gives me "nil" for the `createdBy` value.

I've tried following the `Parse` docs, but I honestly don't know what I'm doing. This is my first app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is save a `userID` per product object. In fact, every user already has a property called `objectId` when you create a new parse user object. You can use this **unique identifier** to set to a property called `userID` in every product object. Or if you would like it to be the user's email, make sure the email is stored to the user:

```
let user = PFUser()
// Fill in the rest here...
user.setObject("someone@somewhere.com", forKey: "email")
user.save()
```

And then when you create your purchase objects (make sure you have an instantiated `user` below

```
let product = PFProduct()
// Fill in the rest here...
product.setObject(user["email"], forKey: "purchaserEmail")
product.save()
```

So then when you are trying to check for the email associated with the purchaser of that product

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let product: PFProduct = self.products.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFProduct

    var purchaserEmail: String = product["purchaserEmail"]

    println("Go spam \(purchaserEmail) more.")
}
```

And you can do the same with the username of the user if you'd like to save that to the product object as well. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I think in your query where you pull the information from Parse you need to use the `includeKey` parameter.

It would look like this:

`query.includeKey("user")` and that should allow you to get at that user info.